# CalenderList.List().Execute() Not returning, Google calender API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working with google calendar API, to retrieve all the events for a specified calendar. After setting up my credentials and calling the following, to get a list of all my  calenders:

```
     var test = service.Calendars.Get(id).Execute();
```

The Execite() is making the call to the google server, but I'm not getting a response from that call. And it stays in this idle state.

public static ServiceAccountCredential Authenticate()
        {

```
        string serviceAccountEmail = "...@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        string keyFilePath = @"filepath";

        // what googleApi features to access
           _scopes = new string[]
        {
            CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
            CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
        };

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
             new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
             {

                 Scopes = _scopes
             }.FromCertificate(certificate));


        return credential;
    }



 public class GoogleCalenderRepository
 {
    ServiceAccountCredential _credentials;

    public GoogleCalenderRepository()
    {
        _credentials = GoogleServiceAccountAuthentication.Authenticate();
    }
    // use async and await
    public string RoomAvailability()
    {
        CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = _credentials,
            ApplicationName = "My Project",
        });

        var calender = service.Calendars.Get("@...group.calendar.google.com").Execute();

        return null;
    }
 }
```

edit: when call the Execute() in my output screen I'm getting:

The thread 0x13f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: If calendars is null then the user you are authenticating with doesn't have any calendars on there calendar list or you are using a service account and have not inserted any calendars to it.

Comment: I'm using a service account. The Execute() simply not returning back to the calling code. The calender, I'm sharing with the service account email ...@developer.gservericeaccount.com

Comment: Am I right in saying the calendars in my google account won't appear in my service account? If So, How do I read calenders from my google account, into service account? thanks

Comment: You are correct, your personal calendars will not be available to the service account by default you need to share them with it.

Answer (score 1):

This example is in VB.NET extracted from my live application.

It shows you how to call the Google Calendar API to get the list of Calendars for your username. You can translate to C# manually or by using one of the online services.

```
    Dim objCalendarListRequest As CalendarListResource.ListRequest
    Dim objCalendars As Data.CalendarList
    objCalendarListRequest = objCalendarService.CalendarList.List
    objCalendars = objCalendarListRequest.Execute()
    For Each objCal As Data.CalendarListEntry In objCalendars.Items
        If objCal.Primary IsNot Nothing AndAlso objCal.Primary Then
            Debug.WriteLine("ID=" & objCal.Id & ", Description=" & objCal.Description & ", Summary=" & objCal.Summary)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```